# Legal situation for roving in Sweden

Tags: archery, legality, sweden, roving

I want to go on a trip to Sweden next summer. However, the plan was to do a little [roving](http://www.stickbow.com/FEATURES/HISTORY/roving.CFM) in the untouched nature. *Note: I'll bring my own [field target with me](http://shop.flibo-bogensport.eu/media/image/thumbnail/rinehart-field-target-ball_720x600.jpg) to not harm any nature.*

> Roving can be described in the most casual form as wandering across
>   the countryside shooting at targets picked from random at various
>   ranges and attitudes.

Due to the fact that the bow is a "sporting equipment" in my country, it's fully okay to go roving as long as you have field tips attached (what I have of course).

I wonder if that is the case in Sweden, too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hunting with bow is not allowed in Sweden, but a bow does not require a license, and the Swedish law for the nature ("allemandsretten") is very liberal, so I guess it is ok shoot at targets, when not near any people.

The Swedish weapons guide (in Swedish, sorry)

https://polisen.se/Global/www%20och%20Intrapolis/FAP/FAP551_3_RPSFS2009_13.pdf

---

> ### Bows
>
> A bow is not regarded as a weapon according to the Weapons Act. This
>   is because it is not possible to store energy in a bow in the same
>   manner as a crossbow.

From [Tullverket](http://www.tullverket.se/en/travellers/travellingtosweden/armsandotherdangerousarticles/harpoonsandweaponsusingarrows.4.335e16821392faa28dd7d9.html)

As the bow is not a weapon it's from a legal point of view pretty much the same as playing with a ball. It's just okay to go roving with field tips attached.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know if the bow is considered a "weapon" or a "sporting equipment" by law?

Comment: I can't be sure, but as the law guide (above) list bow and arrow with examples like fake guns and air guns, and that it does not require a permit, I would conclude that it is not classified as a weapon. Note that airport security or airlines might classify it as a weapon.

Comment: Hi Stefan! Your second link, to Tullverket, leads to a non-existent page. I'm in America, though, and the page seems to originate in Sweden, so I wonder if it's a language or browser problem. If you'd like to check it, that would be great!

Comment: @OddDeer, would you mind checking to see if that link works for you? I don't know what browser you use, but since you've been more active on the site lately than Stefan, I thought I'd ask, if you have the time. Thanks!

Comment: @Sue Leads to a 404 not found error for me.

Comment: @OddDeer https://polisen.se/siteassets/forfattningssamling/fap-nummer/fap551_3_rpsfs2009_13.pdf should be correct now, at least for some time

Comment: @OddDeer FYI, it says: >3. Pil- eller slangbåge, innefattande även s.k. compoundbåge eller
andra jaktpilbågar.
i.e. bows are explicitly classified as non-weapons, regardless of type